# What exception to catch if db operation fails and I want to retry?

Tags: spring

I would like to catch the exceptions thrown if a database operation fails due to transient errors like network glitches etc and retry the operation a few seconds later.

Comment: This is not you are looking for @user

Comment: I am aware of the retry but the question is what to catch and retry?

Comment: it is really tricky which exception to tell which exceptions causes this failure, so in that case write catch block with `catch(Exception e)` this will catch all exceptions and you can find which exception caused this by using `instanceof` keyword @HeyItsMe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Spring retry dependency which has good retry mechanism, In @Retryable annotation we can specify how many times it should retry, for which exception retry should happen and time intervals.

After all retries failed Recover method gets executed, if there is no recovery method it will blow up with exception, for more info walk through these references [here baeldung](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry) [here second link](https://www.tuturself.com/posts/view?menuId=3&postId=1145)

While doing database operations there is chance of causing exception, but that might be different exceptions, for example

```
ConnectionTimeOutException
ReadTimeOutException
SoucketTimeOutException
```

It is little bit tricky to guess which exception cause this failure. In that case you can use `instanceOf` to find which exception it is and do operations based on that

And also you can use multi catch block, if you aware some exceptions are occuring frequently and want to do same operation for all of them, but multi catch block has some limitations

```
 @Service
 public class TestService {

 @Retryable(value = {SomeException.class, MyException.class}, 
   maxAttempts = 3,backoff = @Backoff(2000))
 public void retryWhenException() {
 try{
    // datebase operation that can fail
 }catch(Exception se){
       //this catch will catch all exceptions 
    if(se instanceof SocketTimeOutException){
      //do something
       }else{
    throw se;
    }
 }catch(MyException| SomeException me){
    // will be retried
    throw me;
 }catch(Exception e){
    // will not be retried
    throw e;
 }
}

@Recover
public void recover(SomeException exception) {
 // recover from SomeException
 }
}
```